# Extracting application icons still null

Tags: java, icons, imageicon

I'm trying to extract an `arraylist` of icon images from a folder, but I keep getting a NullPointerException. I can already extract the smaller versions, but they are too small. The icons I'm trying to get are regular sized icons. `filePaths` holds the list of icon locations. `iconBIG.add(...)` is where the `NullPointerException` error is pointing to.

```
// Global
private ArrayList<Icon> iconBIG = new ArrayList<Icon>();

// Within extractIcon()...
for (String target : filePaths)
    {
        try 
        {
            ShellFolder shell = ShellFolder.getShellFolder(new File(target));
            iconBIG.add(new ImageIcon(shell.getIcon(true)));    
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** I already have full permission to use ShellFolder.

**UPDATE:** Where it says `new File(target)` (which only holds the complete paths of the applications), if I change

`getShellFolder(new File(target)`

to

`getShellFolder(new File(C:/foo/bar.lnk)`,

the code works. I've already figured beforehand to replace all `\` with '/', but I don't understand why it's still calling the same error.

Comment: is `iconBIG` initialized before this code block?

Comment: @Abu yes. It is global

Comment: What's ShellFolder? It's not part of the start card JDK (as far as I can see)

Comment: @MadProgrammer http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0439.html Its not documented. In Eclipse, Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Error Message -> Deprecated and Restricted API -> set Forbidden References to Ignore

Comment: Have you checked if `shell` and `iconBIG` is null?

Comment: @VishalK I've already checked. Data is there. Check my update. Just found out entering the path by hand works, trying to figure out why its not working as is

Comment: @SpicyWeenie in your update you mention *'it's still calling the same error'*. What error? Also *'complete paths'* is misleading, what kind of paths do you have, can you give an example?

Comment: @Aqua The complete path to the icon in the folder. If I dont explicitly write out a path ("C:\\foo\\bar\\foobar.txt") inside new File(), I will get a NullPointerException. But if I do replace "target" with the above path (as in type it in by hand), the code works. I checked the Arraylist of Strings containing the paths, an they are all fine. Don't know why it doesn't like variables.

Comment: @SpicyWeenie Maybe one of items in `filePaths` is `null`. That is probably the reason for NPE. Debug or just print every `target` in that loop to console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work Ok, given that you allowed execution of this private package. Here is an example that works on JDK 6:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.swing.*;
import sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder;

public class ShowShellIcon {
    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Load Image");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton loadButton = new JButton("Display Image");
        loadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(
                        System.getProperty("user.home"));
                if (fc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                    try {
                        ShellFolder shell = ShellFolder.getShellFolder(fc
                                .getSelectedFile());
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                new ImageIcon(shell.getIcon(true)));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        frame.add(loadButton);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } 
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it only shows folders and not folder and files

Comment: It is not a problem, it was filtering folders only, I removed that line - `fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);`. It shows files now. See updated code.